# Trace32 - reading ASCII from memory into macro/variable

Tags: trace32

I would like to know the proper way of reading a memory chunk which is plain ASCII into a variable (Practice macro). This is apparently possible for simple integer types, with
`Data.Long()`. However, conversion to ASCII would be cumbersome.

I tried finding this in Lauterbach manuals but in this area they are quite misleading, mixing visualization in UI with data processing. I do not need this in the UI. I only need this string in a variable for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Data.STRING() function to store zero-terminated strings into a PRACTICE macro:

```
&text=Data.STRing(<address>)
```

Comment: I found Data.STRingN() to be more suitable for the purpose, though.